# Upper Bound on the entries of $A^n$, where $A \in M_d(\mathbb C)$ and $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{1\le i,j\le d} \in M_d(\mathbb C)$ for fixed $d\in \mathbb N$. We denote the entries of $A^n$ by $$A^n = [a_{ij}^{(n)}]_{1\le i,j\le d}$$
for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

> Claim: If $M > 0$ is such that $|a_{ij}|\le M$ for all $1\le i,j\le d$, then $$|a_{ij}^{(n)}|\le (dM)^n$$
> for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

*Proof.* I have proved this claim by induction. The base case is trivial, since $d\ge 1$.  It is easily seen that $$\left|a_{ij}^{(n+1)}\right| = \left|\sum_{p=1}^d a_{ip}^{(n)} a_{pj}\right| \le \sum_{p=1}^d |a_{ip}^{(n)}|| a_{pj}| \le \sum_{p=1}^d (dM)^n M = (dM)^{n+1}$$

**Questions:**

1. I am looking for direct proofs (i.e. without induction) of the above result. Could I get some suggestions?
2. Are better bounds known? That is, can we find $\lambda(M,n,d)$ such that if $|a_{ij}|\le M$ for all $1\le i,j\le d$, then $|a_{ij}^{(n)}|\le \lambda(M,n,d)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, where $\lambda(M,n,d) < (dM)^n$?

Comment: I dont think there's any better bound: try with $A = MI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of order $d$.

Comment: I think the least upper bound is $d^{n-1}M^n$. It is attained by the all-one matrix or its scalar multiples.

Comment: In some cases, one can look at eigenvalues of $A$ and try to estimate $n-th$ power of $A$ by them using the fact that if $A= B*C*B^{-1}$ then $A^n = B*C^n*B^{-1}$.

Comment: @user1551 How would you prove that $$|a_{ij}|\le M \text{ for all }1\le i,j\le d \implies |a_{ij}^{(n)}|\le d^{n-1}M^n \text{ for all } n\in \mathbb N$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best upper bound is $d^{n-1}M^n$:
\begin{aligned}
|(A^n)_{ij}|
&=\left|\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in[d]^{n-1}} a_{ik_1}a_{k_1k_2}\cdots a_{k_{n-1}j}\right|\\
&\le\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in[d]^{n-1}} |a_{ik_1}a_{k_1k_2}\cdots a_{k_{n-1}j}|\\
&\le\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in[d]^{n-1}}M^n\\
&=d^{n-1}M^n.
\end{aligned}
This bound is sharp. It is attained when every element of $A$ is equal to $M$.